# One Opengl ES Program for each texture?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm learning to program in OpenGL ES

My questions are:

I want to draw two pictures, each with its texture.

To do this I create two Opengl ES Program?

You can use the same Opengl ES Program for each texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using OpenGL ES 2.0 or 1.1? With 2.0, at least one pair of shader programs (vertex and fragment) is required, which can render any number of textures.  To change to a different texture, just use glBindTexture().  With 1.1, you can do the same, but there are no shader programs.

Comment: My problem was that not indicate which texture was used.
For this reason were drawn with the same texture.

I use the function which you Indicated:

// Here I indicate which texture will use
//(This was what I needed)
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
//Then the program to use
GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);


Note, I have a list of instances of the same class, so textureID is different in each instance.

thank you very much